# Animate on Scroll (AOS) animations do not work when HTML5 video element is on page

Tags: javascript, animation, scroll, html5-video

I have an HTML5 video element on my page, and my animations are not working. They work on every other page of the website. Here is my video code:

```
<div class="video-wrapper">
    <div class="video">
       <video poster="/images/video.png" autoplay="" loop="" muted="" playsinline="">
           <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
       </video>
    </div>
</div>
```

That video element is at the top of the page, above any animated items. When I move the video underneath the animated items (to the footer), remove the video altogether, or "live edit" it out using the firefox dev console, the animations start working again.

I also live edited it into the AOS page (https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/) and it broke the animations there as well. The animations worked when I moved the video to the bottom of that page as well.

Is this a known compatibility issue with HTML5 video and AOS? Any way to fix the problem?

Comment: On further inspection and testing, it appears that the animations DO indeed work, but they are triggering too early... I assume because of the full width and result tall height of the video. How can we make sure that AOS takes into account the height of the video element in regards to when animations are being triggered?

Comment: aaaaand upon even further inspection, it appears that the issue only occurs when the video element is contained within a parent div. If the video element is just floating in the code (essentially a child of the <body> element), then the animations run as expected. Still seems like a buggy sort of thing though... why shouldn't it work while contained in a div? Any fix?

Comment: Here is a fiddle. To see the animations work, remove the <div> wrapper from acount the video element: https://jsfiddle.net/x4t1gb9L/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to "fix" the issue by giving the video element an absolute position, and then adding a 1600x900px transparent PNG in the same parent div to "stretch" the entire parent container to the height of the 16x9 video.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I used.

HTML

```html
    <section id="sec1" class="position-relative">
        <img class="w-100 d-block" src="assets/images/eyes-masked.jpg" alt="eyes-masked">
        <video class="d-block w-100 video" playsinline autoplay muted loop>
            <source id="mp4_src" src="assets/images/eyes.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            No tiene visor de video. Actualice su navegador.
        </video>
    </section>
```

CSS

```css
    .video {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
```